# How to get the sql generated by the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

How can I  get the sql script generated by an entity framework query?
i.e. If I write

```
entityDataDontext.table1.Where(r => r.primarykey == 1).First();
```

then how can I get the SQL which should be somewhat like this:

```
select * from table1 where primarykey = 1
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please see duplicates: [How do I view the SQL generated by the entity framework ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework) [SQL tracing LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137712/sql-tracing-linq-to-entities)

Comment: `var trace = ((ObjectQuery<T>)query).ToTraceString()`

Comment: I'd like to add to @RPM1984 comment that to use this against an anonymous type you would use `ObjectQuery` rather than `ObjectQuery<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

When you're going against SQL Server as your backend database, **SQL Server Profiler** is always the best tool to see exactly what SQL statements are being sent to your database to be processed.

See [Introducting SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) for background info.

Answer (score 2):

I can strongly recommend MiniProfiler:
http://miniprofiler.com/

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the SQL Server Profiler, you can try [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/), which does that and more.

It's paid, with a 30-day trial.

Comment: I have used this earlier, it's a very good tool. The only problem is that it is paid :(