# Validate that EF can understand expression tree

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I wonder if there is any way to validate a Expression towards EF core without using a real database.

We could of course do the validation in a integration tests, but It would be very helpful if we could ensure that the expression is valid already in a unit test.

To me, a novice, it feels like pretty basic functionality. Despite this I have yet to find any solution when looking around on the internet.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit:
To summarize, I do not need to validate the sql ( does it find table X etc ) rather I only want to know that EF can generate a query string from the expression tree.

Comment: You can only validate in a test using the targeted provider. But you can Make that test run really fast.

Comment: Just do `query.ToQueryString()` which makes EF translate the expression without executing it.

Comment: Entity Framework is an abstraction layer for interacting with a database. What are you having problems with? Writing code? -- Which a unit test can check. Or when EF translates your query to the underlying database provider and then executes it on the database? -- which you won't be able to check without executing it on the actual database.

Comment: @GertArnold Good idea, but it does not seem to work here; "The given 'IQueryable' does not support generation of query strings."

Comment: @BurnsBA I find this strange. At some point before sending the query towards the database EF does a translation of the expression tree into a sql statement. I simply want to do that without an database running.

Comment: Printing the generated SQL is a different question from validation. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1412863/1462295 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4700400/1462295

Comment: @BurnsBA That is fair, I have updated the question